# NSCollectionViewItem does not display custom view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem`, called `ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem`. Using this, I want to display a custom view represented by `ZMSDKThumbnailVideoItemView`.

`ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem` is represented by a XIB file. This contains exactly one `NSView` which's class is set (using Identity Inspector) to `ZMSDKThumbnailVideoItemView`.

```
@interface ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem : NSCollectionViewItem
@property (assign) IBOutlet ZMSDKThumbnailVideoItemView *videoItemView;
@end
```

In my `NSCollectionViewDataSource` I create items like this:

```
- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem* item = [collectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:@"ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ZMSDKThumbnailVideoItemView* thumbnailView = [_thumbnailVideoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    // IBOutlet videoItemView
    item.videoItemView = thumbnailView;

    return item;
}
```

Problem: although `_thumbnailVideoArray` contains elements, nothing is displayed in the collection view.

When I modify `ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem` so that it contains a `NSLabel` instead of a `ZMSDKThumbnailVideoItemView`, the items are being displayed properly.

**Question: in which manner do I have to create a `NSCollectionViewItem` to display a custom view?** Is it correct to set the class of the containing view in the XIB file to `ZMSDKThumbnailVideoItemView` like I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found the solution.

Instead of changing the class of the item's view, one has to add a sub view to the item's view:

```
- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem* item = [collectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:@"ZMSDKThumbnailCollectionViewItem" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ZoomSDKVideoElement* thumbnailView = [_videoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    [item.view addSubview:[thumbnailView getVideoView]];

    return item;
}
```